# Remove first column from text file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

I have following file with these lines:

```
"A,B,C,D","E","F","G","H"
```

How I can easily remove first column in quotas?

Finally I want to see:

```
"E","F","G","H"
```

Comment: it is always fixed the first column or it is also required to remove other columns? like 38th col, 5th col etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way also

```
sed 's/^"[^"]\+",//' FileName.txt
```

**Output:**

```
"E","F","G","H"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/^"[^"]*",//' YourFile
```

Assuming:

- there is no `\"` in double quoted string
- field are double quoted (in fact, at least first one)
- there is no extra space between field value and `,` (easy to adapt in this case)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'[",]' -v OFS=\",\" '{print "\""$5,$6,$7,$8"\""}' file

"E","F","G","H"
```